# How to make swiftui struct mutable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following struct:

```swift
struct Communication: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let message, title: String
    let date: Date
    var isExpanded: Bool = false
}
```

The problem is that when I try to change the value of `isExpanded` I get the error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'communication' is a 'let' constant

I am trying to use it inside a `List()` in `SwiftUI`

What would be a proper solution to this type of problem in Swift?

I use the class `DatabaseService` to fetch the results:

```
class DatabaseService : ObservableObject {

@Published var communications = [Communication]()

funct getCommunications() -> Void {
    //...Add items to communications
}
```

And then in my view

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var databaseService = DatabaseService()

    var body: some View {
        List(databaseService.communications) { communication in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(communication.title)
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title3)
                    Text(communication.message)
                        .padding(.bottom, 24)
                        .lineLimit(communication.isExpanded ? nil : 5)
                        .overlay(
                            GeometryReader { proxy in
                                Button(action: {
                                    communication.isExpanded.toggle()
                                }) {
                                    Text(communication.isExpanded ? "Mai puțin" : "Mai mult")
                                        .font(.caption).bold()
                                        .padding(.leading, 8.0)
                                        .padding(.top, 8.0)
                                }
                                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                            }
                        )
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                self.databaseService.getComunicate()
            })
    }
```

Comment: I think it's because you are creating a `Communication` variable that is `let`. Search in your code `let communication` and change it to `var communication`. It have nothing to do with the struct itself

Comment: @אוריorihpt it's a List in swiftui, that variable is the iteration from the list.

Comment: It depends on how do you define it in your SwiftUI view. Would you show related view?

Comment: @Asperi I have changed the question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleanest to extract the selection logic to your DatabaseService:

```
class DatabaseService : ObservableObject {

    @Published private(set) var communications = [Communication]()

    public func didSelect(_ communication: Communication) -> Void {
    
        // find the index of the communication tapped by user
        guard let selectedIndex = communications.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == comunication.id }) else {
            return
        }
        // make a local copy so you can mutate it
        var communication = communication
        // toggle the selection
        comunication.selected.toggle()
        // assign the updated value to right index in the array, which will trigger the Publisher
        communications[selectedIndex] = comunication
    
    }

 }
```

Then in your View you can call the function like this:

```
Button(action: { databaseService.didSelect(communication) })
```

And you don't need to change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, inside `ForEach` container you work with constant copy of data element, so it is not possible to change it (even if you would, anyway it is a copy so no sense). Instead we have to modify corresponding element *inside* view model collection, like

```
@ObservedObject var ds = DatabaseService()    // << to shorten
var body: some View {
    List(ds.communications.indices, id: \.self) { i in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(ds.communications[i].title)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.title3)
                Text(ds.communications[i].message)
                    .padding(.bottom, 24)
                    .lineLimit(ds.communications[i].isExpanded ? nil : 5)
                    .overlay(
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            Button(action: {
                                ds.communications[i].isExpanded.toggle() // << now modified in VM !!
                            }) {
                                Text(ds.communications[i].isExpanded ? "Mai puțin" : "Mai mult")
                                    .font(.caption).bold()
                                    .padding(.leading, 8.0)
                                    .padding(.top, 8.0)
                            }
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                        }
                    )
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't our object extend something so we can use id: \.self ?

Comment: We iterate by indices, not objects.